# How to create a file even root user also can't delete? Is there any possiblities?

Tags: filesystem

Is there any way to create to a file that root user also cant delete?

Answer (score 2):

It's possible only with hardware-restricted write capabilities.

But if you want prevent some files from being accidentally deleted e.g. with

```
rm -rf /some/dir
```

Try to set immutable attribute:

```
: ~ $ touch immut
: ~ $ sudo chattr +i immut 
: ~ $ sudo rm immut 
rm: cannot remove 'immut': Operation not permitted
```

Answer (score 1):

> Root privileges are the powers that the root account has on the
>   system. The root account is the most privileged on the system and has
>   absolute power over it (i.e., complete access to all files and
>   commands).

Nothing is impossible for a root user to do. There is no way To do that.

```
: ~ $ touch immut
: ~ $ sudo chattr +i immut 
: ~ $ sudo rm immut 
rm: cannot remove 'immut': Operation not permitted
```

But admin still return attributes back

```
: ~ $ sudo chattr -i immut 
: ~ $ sudo rm immut
```

done!!!